# Two Tab-Separated Delimiter in Python Writing to TSV

Tags: python, csv, writer

I have the following code:

```
f = open("test.tsv", 'wt')
try:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    for x in range(0, len(ordered)):
        writer.writerow((ordered[x][0],"\t", ordered[x][1]))
finally:
    f.close()
```

I need the TSV file to have the ordered[x][0] separated by two tabs with ordered[x][1]
the "\t" adds space, but its not a tab and the parentheses are shown on the output.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the `"\t"` by `""` to obtain what you want:

```
writer.writerow((ordered[x][0],"", ordered[x][1]))
```

Indeed, the empty string in the middle will then be surrounded by a tab on both sides, effectively putting two tabs between `ordered[x][0]` and `ordered[x][1]`.

However, a more natural code doing exactly the same thing would be:

```
with open("test.tsv", "w") as fh:
    for e in ordered:
        fh.write("\t\t".join(map(str, e[:2])) + "\n")
```

where I:

- used a `with` statement (explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)) instead of the `try ... finally` construct
- removed the `t` mode in the `open` function (`t` is the default behavior)
- iterated over the elements in `ordered` using `for ... in` instead of using an index
- used `join` instead of a csv  writer: those are suited in cases where the delimiter is a single character